# How would I allow a variety of different syntaxes for passing arguments into MathJax or LaTeX commands?

Tags: compilers, parsing, interpreters, lexing

## What is *LaTeX*

If you already know what *LaTeX* is, then skip down the the section labeled "***sloppy syntax***".

There is a type-setting language known as [**LaTeX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX).

[**LaTeX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) even has its very own Stack Exchange Site located [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

You do not have have to be fluent in [**MathJax**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or [**LaTeX**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) in order to answer this question.

However, it does help to see three examples of the syntax for **LaTeX**:

```LaTeX
\kiwi{a+06}{b+09}{x+11}
\binom{n+1}{2k}
\foobar{100}
\jackfruit{1.1}{2.2}{3.33}{4.444}{5.555}{6}
```

**LaTeX** has various ***commands*** and those ***commands*** behave somewhat like the ***functions*** we find in other programming languages.

`\binom{n+1}{2k}` is an example of a **LaTeX** command with two parameters passed into it.

So, the `binom` command (like a function or procedure) accepts two input arguments. The input arguments are `n+1` and `2k`.

---

## Sloppy Syntax

Suppose that you wanted to translate something named **LearnTex** into **LaTeX**.

Our imaginary **LearnTex** is a bit like a pre-processor, or macro, for **LaTeX**

The primary goal here is to make the **LaTeX** language easier for new people to learn.

**LearnTex** would allow correctly spelled **LaTeX**, so it is backwards compatible.

We can define **wrapping delimiters** as follows:

> - curly braces `{}`
> - square brackets `[]`
> - parentheses  `()`

---

Below are the infix delimiters of interest within the current context:

> - commas `,`
> - colons `:`
> - semi-colons `;`

---

Ideally, any infix delimiter in **LearnTex** would be exchangeable (swappable) for any other infix delimiter.

For example, `\binom{n+1, 2k}` with a comma and `\binom{n+1; 2k}` with a semi-colon would eventually compile into the same thing.

| Example No | INPUT (**LearnTex** ) | OUTPUT (**LaTeX**) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `\dfrac{1}{x}` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 2 | `\dfrac{1, x}` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 3 | `\dfrac(1, x)` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 4 | `\dfrac[1; x]` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 5 | `\dfrac(1; x)` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 6 | `\dfrac(1)(x)` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |
| 7 | `\dfrac[1][x]` | `\dfrac{1}{x}` |

In additional to commas (`,`) being swappable with semi-colons (`;`) and colons (`:`), we need functions to look like they are [curried](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=what%20is%20computer%20programming%20curry).

For example,

```LaTeX
\command{x}{y}{z}
\command{x, y, z}
```

I wrote, "*look like curry*", because we **not** have to have an actual programming curry implementation, like this:

> `SUM(1, 2, 3)` is implemented as:
>
> - Function call `f1(1)` returns function `f2`
> - Function call `f2(2)` returns function `f3`
> - Function call `f3(3)` returns `6` which is `1+2+3`.

Instead of implementing curry at a low-level, our goal is to simply replace some ASCII-encoded strings with some other ASCII-encoded strings.

For example, `\cmd{1, 2}` becomes `\cmd{1}{2}`

Pretend we don't support all of latex. Our interpreter or parser need only translate one command at a time.

In case you are curious, a regular expression for a command with a single input is:

```None
\\[a-zA-Z]+[{(\[][a-zA-Z0-9]+[})\]]
```

In the end, a LaTeX compiler or interpreter will be used to either interpret or compile the LaTeX into a human-readable pdf file full of a mixture mathematical equations and English.

For example, `\dfrac{n}{d}` becomes the fraction *n* divided by *d*.

---

## What approach would you recommend for converting **LearnTex** into **LaTeX**?

Comment: That regex doesn't look correct - at least not when `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms see https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/

Comment: @RubenVerg: I would take the regex as prescribing syntax of LearnTeX rather than describing syntax of TeX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's requesting implementation advice for a very specific problem, not particularly transferrable to other contexts on the site. I think it would be better suited on StackOverflow (although read their [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guide first)

Answer (score 1):

I would

1. parse the LearnTeX syntax using a parsing library, such as [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language))'s [`combine`](https://lib.rs/crates/combine) or [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell)'s [`parsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec), or a parser generator, such as [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCaml)'s [`menhir`](https://pauillac.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/) or Rust's [`lalrpop`](https://lib.rs/crates/lalrpop), and then
2. generate the equivalent TeX syntax (LaTeX is essentially a standard library for TeX, not its own language).  This does not necessarily mean parsing all the input into an intermediate representation that would live in memory in its entirety; the parser could *stream* information to the generator.  For that, in Rust, one could use an [iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html), whereas, in Haskell, I guess the language's lazy evaluation would make the program naturally do this.

However, for demonstration, **here's a very manual implementation of a very direct, imperative translator of LearnTeX into TeX**, written in Rust but in a style intended to be accessible to programmers who are familiar with C-family languages other than Rust.  This implementation is tested at the end.  It and its tests can be **[run in the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b105acd26845d9f38b7499827a526794)** (click the big red "TEST" button in the top left corner).

```rust
/// Translates LearnTeX, a syntactic variant of TeX, into TeX
///
/// See <https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1045>.
///
/// This instead, of course, could be written in a functional style;
/// or as a lazy [iterator], which *might* be more efficient when
/// optimized by the compiler; but it is written in an imperative
/// style for clarity to most programmers.
///
/// It could be useful to extend this LearnTeX syntax to allow
/// escaping the argument separators by wrapping them in braces, so
/// that `\command{{a, b, c}}` is translated literally as
/// `\command{{a, b, c}}`, which is largely equivalent to `\command{a,
/// b, c}` for the commands that MathJax supports.
///
/// [iterator]: <https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html>
pub fn learntex_to_tex(input: &str) -> String {
    // `with_capacity` is merely an optimization: we guess that the
    // output will be about as long as the input, so we allocate an
    // output buffer as long as the input, to reduce the number of
    // times that `output`'s backing buffer will need to be grown (and
    // thus reallocated) as we append content from the input to it.
    let mut output = String::with_capacity(input.len());

    // Iterate over the characters in the input.  It would be much
    // more idiomatic and more efficient Rust to use the
    // `input.chars()` iterator to iterate over the characters
    // directly, but instead we iterate by character index, for
    // clarity to non-Rust programmers.
    let mut chars = input.chars();

    // While there is still `Some` character left, iterate over the
    // characters.  When there are no characters left, the `chars`
    // iterator's `next()` method will return `None` and the loop will
    // stop.
    'outer_loop: while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        // Switch on what the character is here.
        match c {
            '\\' => {
                // We have encountered a command.  Append a backslash
                // to the output.
                output.push('\\');

                // Command names consist of, and only of, alphabetic
                // characters.  Loop, appending these to the output,
                // until we encounter a non-alphabetic character,
                // which is either the opening delimiter of the
                // command's arguments or (if the command has no
                // arguments) something that is not an opening
                // delimiter.
                let mut char_after_command_name = None;
                while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
                    if c.is_alphabetic() {
                        output.push(c);
                    } else {
                        char_after_command_name = Some(c);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                let opening_delimiter;
                match char_after_command_name {
                    Some(c @ ('{' | '[' | '(')) => {
                        // LearnTeX allows any of `{...}`, `[...]`,
                        // `(...)` to stand for TeX's `{...}`.  The
                        // `@` means to capture the opening delimiter
                        // as a variable named `c`.  Now we set the
                        // enclosing scope's `opening_delimiter`
                        // variable to that.
                        opening_delimiter = c;
                    }

                    Some(other_char) => {
                        // This command has ended.  Append the
                        // following character to the output and
                        // continue the outer loop.
                        output.push(other_char);
                        continue 'outer_loop;
                    }

                    None => {
                        // The input has ended.  End the outer loop.
                        break 'outer_loop;
                    }
                }

                let mut skip_space = false;

                // Loop, parsing the command's arguments.
                'args_loop: loop {
                    // We are in a command's argument.  Output the TeX
                    // opening delimiter for an argument.  LearnTeX
                    // supports only those TeX commands that use
                    // `{...}`-delimited arguments only, no
                    // `[...]`-delimited optional arguments or fancy
                    // `xparse` arguments.
                    output.push('{');

                    // Decide which delimiter will be needed to close
                    // this argument.
                    let closing_delimiter = match opening_delimiter {
                        '{' => '}',
                        '[' => ']',
                        '(' => ')',
                        _ => unreachable!(),
                    };

                    loop {
                        match chars.next() {
                            Some(',' | ';' | ':') => {
                                // Any of these three characters is
                                // allowed as an argument separator,
                                // so this argument ends here and a
                                // new one begins.  Output the TeX
                                // closing delimiter for an argument.
                                output.push('}');
                                // The argument separator may be
                                // followed by any amount of
                                // whitespace, which is ignored.
                                skip_space = true;
                                // Continue to the next argument.
                                continue 'args_loop;
                            }

                            Some(c) if c == closing_delimiter => {
                                // We have encountered the end of the
                                // argument list.  Output the TeX
                                // closing delimiter for an argument.
                                output.push('}');
                                break 'args_loop;
                            }

                            Some(c) if skip_space && c.is_whitespace() => {
                                // Ignore the whitespace.
                            }

                            Some(other_char) => {
                                // This character is part of an
                                // argument.  Output it.
                                output.push(other_char);
                                // Also, we encountered a non-space
                                // character, so stop skipping spaces.
                                skip_space = false;
                            }

                            None => {
                                // The argument was not closed.  In
                                // practice, there are much more
                                // graceful and helpful ways of
                                // handling such an error than
                                // throwing this exception.
                                panic!("unclosed argument");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            other_char => {
                // We encountered some character that is not part of a
                // command.  Append the character to the output.
                output.push(other_char);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the output.
    output
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"abc"), r"abc");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc"), r"\abc");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{}"), r"\abc{}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x}"), r"\abc{x}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x]"), r"\abc{x}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x)"), r"\abc{x}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x, y}"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x, y]"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x, y)"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x, y, z}"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x, y, z]"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x, y, z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x; y}"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x; y]"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x; y)"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x; y; z}"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x; y; z]"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x; y; z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x: y}"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x: y]"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x: y)"), r"\abc{x}{y}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x: y: z}"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x: y: z]"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x: y: z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x, y; z}"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc[x; y, z]"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x, y: z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x: y, z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x; y: z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc(x: y; z)"), r"\abc{x}{y}{z}");
    assert_eq!(learntex_to_tex(r"\abc{x} def \ghi[y]"), r"\abc{x} def \ghi{y}");
}
```

If you are interested in seeing this done with `combine`, I can write an example of that.

Edit: My manual implementation is wrong in that it does not translate commands with 'curried' arguments, i.e., it translates `\abc(x)[y]` as `\abc{x}[y]`, seeing the `[y]` as not an argument to the command. I'm trying to fix this.